# Multipage: Navigator & Navigation setup -> "Component must be attached to a session when getConnectorId() is called for the first time"

Tags: java, spring, gradle, vaadin, vaadin8

i cannot get a navigator to run within my project.
i always get the Error 
"Component must be attached to a session when getConnectorId() is called for the first time"

i followed several examples where it ran out of the box with nealy the exact same setup but i cannot get it to run within my environment and i don't know why.

This is my MainUI

```
@SpringUI
public class MainUI extends UI implements View{

HorizontalLayout root;

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    root = new HorizontalLayout();

    VerticalLayout menu = this.createMenuBar();
    menu.setWidth("20%");
    root.addComponents(menu);

    Panel viewPanel = new Panel();
    root.addComponentsAndExpand(viewPanel);

    setContent(root);

    final Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, viewPanel);
    navigator.addView("Food", FoodView.class);
    navigator.addView("Meal", MealView.class);
    navigator.addView("", MainView.class);

    // even with 
    //navigator.addView("Main", MainView.class);
    //navigator.navigateTo("Main");
    // i get the same error
}

@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
    // TODO 
}

private VerticalLayout createMenuBar() {
    VerticalLayout menuBar = new VerticalLayout();
    for(String s: new String[] {"Food", "Meal"}) {
        menuBar.addComponents(this.createNavigationButton(s, this.getNavigator()));
    }

    return menuBar;
}

private Button createNavigationButton(final String state, final Navigator navigator) {
    return new Button("Go go" + state, new Button.ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            navigator.navigateTo(state);
        }
    });     
}

}
```

This is my Main/Food/Meal View, they are only stumps with only a label because i just wanted to test a Multipage example

```
@SpringView(name = MainView.VIEW_NAME)
public class MainView extends UI implements View {

public static final String VIEW_NAME = "Main";

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

    VerticalLayout root = new VerticalLayout();
    setContent(root);

    Label lbl = new Label("MainView");
    root.addComponent(lbl);
}

@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {


}


}
```

Comment: `MainView` should probably extend `VerticalLayout` (or `CustomComponent` or whatever you need) instead of `UI`, and also I don't see why your `MainUI` would implement `View` since it kind of represents [_your application_](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html) and not some of its [views](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/navigator/View.html).

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: thanks @Morfic
Your comment lead me to my issue.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that